# Need help configuring MongoDB on Spring/Maven

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

When I code in Spring, I always use annotations, and always get stuck when it comes to xml based configuration. Right now, I'm stuck at a problem which is probably a very simple thing. I'd appreciate if you could help me out on this.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:888)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:273)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver.getTypeVariableMap(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/util/Map; from class org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:96)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<clinit>(ClassTypeInformation.java:42)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper.<clinit>(DefaultMongoTypeMapper.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.getDefaultMongoConverter(MongoTemplate.java:1691)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.<init>(MongoTemplate.java:175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    ... 26 more
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="co.jobstix.controller">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <context:component-scan base-package="co.jobstix.service">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
    <mongo:db-factory dbname="jobstix" />

    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**SpringMongoConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig {

    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "yourdb");
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Please provide the error log also.

Answer (score 8):

An `IllegalAccessError` in compiled code (not involving reflection) usually means a version mismatch: Client code was compiled against a version of the dependency where a member had a more permissive access modifier. Update your Maven dependencies.

(Since this is a very old question that got recently bumped: The versions involved are all obsolete and should be upgraded to modern versions, which should resolve the problem.)

Comment: that, or there is a version mismatch in the spring jars themselves (mix of different versions of spring libraries). Without pom we can't know.

Comment: @eis All I'm saying is that *some* dependencies don't match, and updating everything should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
    !.  Changes in Xml

    spring-servlet.xml you can also change name with spring-servlet.xml to yourProjectName-servlet.xml

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd

          change to 1.1

                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.1.xsd



    <mongo:mongo host="localhost" port="27017">

    <mongo:options connections-per-host="100"
   threads-allowed-to-block-for-connection-multiplier="5"
            max-wait-time="120000000"
            connect-timeout="10000000"
            socket-keep-alive="true"
            socket-timeout="15000000"
            auto-connect-retry="true"/>

    </mongo:mongo>


    <mongo:db-factory dbname="jobstix"
        mongo-ref="mongo" />
    <bean id="mongoTypeMapper"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper">
        <constructor-arg name="typeKey">
            <null />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoMappingContext"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />
    <bean id="mongoConverter"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mappingContext" ref="mongoMappingContext" />
        <property name="typeMapper" ref="mongoTypeMapper"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter" />
        <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION" />
    </bean>

2. Put Four Jars OR Get From Maven

/Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/mongo-java-driver-2.10.1.jar
/Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar
/Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar
/Test/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/spring-data-mongodb-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar

3. In Dao/Service/Controller you can call these connection to Autowired

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations mongoOperation;
```